# slack api request code

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am trying to make my initial GET call to retrieve the code for my token request. I have searched for hours and I cannot figure out why I am getting a CORS error. I have set the redirect url in the admin panel and included in my query params. I have also tried without it. nothing is working.

It should be a simple as this?

```
fetch(`https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic&client_id=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx`)
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

ERROR

```
Fetch API cannot load https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic&client_id=148914445073.148918419105. Redirect from 'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=identity.basic&client_id=xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx' to 'https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxx.xxxxx&scope=identity.basic&team=T4CSWD325' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **redirect** the user to this page, not load the content of the page asynchronously via fetch :D

This is the page where the user approves your application, after which they will be redirected to the callback you specified.

Most apps use the [Add to Slack](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) button to add this to their sites.

More information about the whole OAuth process is here: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth